# Condition, if search bar null then return error html

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I created a search bar in html that searches my mySQL database and displays the results for my search.

My problem is that if I haven't typed anything on the bar it will display the whole table when I do not want that.

My code is this

```
<form action="Artists.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="searchdatabase"<br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="searching" value="Search"><br><br>
```

and I am trying to do this

```
  <?php 

      if( ! mysqli_num_rows($resultsearch) ) {
      echo "Mysql error: " .mysqli_error($mysql); }

      while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($resultsearch)):?>
          <tr>
              <td><?php echo $row['firstname'];?></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['lastname'];?></td>

          </tr>
  <?php endwhile;?>
```

But this is not working,
I am trying to create an if statement on html (I cant use Javascript) so that my code will not display my entire table and will only display the search I wanted once I press the search button.

Comment: Without javascript, you can't do this on the client-side so the form has to send post data. What you're gonna do is simply checking if `$_POST["searchdatabase"]` is empty or not before executing mysql stuff

Comment: check condition like `if(mysqli_num_rows($resultsearch) > 0 ){ } else { }`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have endwhile? Just use {}  for your loop, match your searchdatabase to one of your names in the mysql. If it doesn't appear in the database throw a error. Other wise have it display. Right now you are calling your whole table. $blah = $con, "Select * From somedata where searchdatabase = firstName"; if you need to order by a certain way order by asce or something like that hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

just make the input as 'required'

```html
 <input type="text" name="searchdatabase" required>
```

this way you cant leave the search bar unfilled.